# Why doesn't this time_zone_ptr example contain a memory leak?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, timezone, weak-ptr

I was reading through the boost DateTime library [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.custom_time_zone_ptr), which contains lots of examples such as this one:

```
time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone("MST-07"));
```

I was curious why the use of the keyword 'new' doesn't cause a memory leak?
I investigated the boost source code, and noticed that it has two different versions of the constructor, one with a shared_ptr and another which uses a weak_ptr. Can someone explain to how these work, and why the above line is safe to write?

Answer (score 7):

`time_zone_ptr` is just an alias for `boost::shared_ptr<time_zone>`. This is a smart pointer which *takes ownership* of a dynamically allocated object, from a raw pointer to which it is constructed.